# Ion encoding not working with php post

Tags: php, android, mysql

im trying to do a post to a php and save in a mysql database

this is the ION.with command:

```
Ion.with(this)
                            .load("http_my_page/test.php")
                            .setBodyParameter("text", "não")


                            .asString(Charset.defaultCharset())//default=UTF-8
                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                                }


                            });
```

my test.php page:

```
<?php
$test  = $_POST["text"]; 
$servername = ...;
$username = "..";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "...";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (my_test) VALUES ('$test')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

and my MYSQL database has a column called my_test and collation is UTF8_unicode_ci

what im specting to store: "não"

what it really store: "nÃ£o"

any reason? since im setting all the econdings =(

Answer (score 0):

That was a PHP/MYSQL encoding issue and nothing related to Ion

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```